# Banach spaces and weak topology

Tags: functional-analysis

Claim : A Banach space V is reflexive iff its unit ball B is weakly compact.

So I want to show that 'unit ball is weakly compact => V is reflexive' without using goldstine.

So I'm trying to use the theorem of bipolars.

From the theorem of bipolars we know that $j(B) = j(B)^{oo}$. So if I can show that $B''\subseteq j(B)^{oo}$, then I will have that $j(B)^{oo}= B''$. And hence $j(B) = B''$, and so j is surjective.

Here $j$ is the canonical projection from $V$ to $V''$

So how do I show $B''\subseteq j(B)^{oo}$

Comment: What's wrong with using Goldstine's theorem (which is quite easy)? If you can show that $B'' \subseteq j(B)^{oo}$ then you will have essentially proved Goldstine's theorem unless you used compactness of $j(B)$ again.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with Golstine's theorem, I just wanted to show it another way. 
Do you have a method with doing it with bipolars?

Comment: Well, I was trying point out that the usual proof of Goldstine's theorem proceeds by showing that $B'' \subseteq j(B)^{oo}$, so no, I don't have a proof with bipolars and **without** Goldstine's theorem. There will at best be some differences in terminology and language.

Comment: $\phi \in B'' \Rightarrow \|\phi\| \leq 1 \Rightarrow |\phi(f)| \leq 1 \ \forall f \in B' \\ \Rightarrow Re\phi(f) \leq 1 \ \forall f \in B'$

And if $f \in V'$ such that $Ref(b) \leq 1 \ \forall b \in B$ then it is clear that $|f(b)| \leq 1 \forall b\in B$

Hence $\|f\| \leq 1 $. So $j(B)^{o} \subseteq B'$. Hence $\phi \in j(B)^{oo}\\$

Does this not prove it? And moreover, I am pretty sure I have not proved Goldstine's theorem?

Comment: I was sloppy reading your statement. I initially thought you meant that Golstine's theorem was needed. Now I believe you meant that just a part of it is.
How did the proof that you saw show this fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\phi \in B'' \Rightarrow \|\phi\| \leq 1 \Rightarrow |\phi(f)| \leq 1 \ \forall f \in B' \\ \Rightarrow Re\phi(f) \leq 1 \ \forall f \in B'$

And if $f \in V'$ such that $Ref(b) \leq 1 \ \forall b \in B$ then it is clear that $|f(b)| \leq 1 \forall b\in B$

Hence $\|f\| \leq 1 $. So $j(B)^{o} \subseteq B'$. Hence $\phi \in j(B)^{oo}$

Here is my attempt. Punch holes as you will...

Comment: +1 that's it. Now combine this with $j(B)\subseteq j(B)^{oo} = \overline{j(B)}^{w\ast}$ and $j(B)\subseteq B''$ and with Alaoglu's theorem and you've proved Goldstine's theorem.